# Fill 3 tables in a Dataset

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I've been reading a lot about this but I haven't come across any solutions. I have a dataset with 3 tables. How can I fill these 3 tables in the dataset?
Is it possible using only one sql query with many joins?

Comment: No, 1 query (adapter) per table. And consider EF instead of Datasets.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tableA where <condition>

select * from tableB where <condition>

select * from tableC where <condition>
```

will return three tables (DataSet)